# how to disable freemarker FTL parser for whole file?

Tags: freemarker

I have webapp with a FreeMarkerViewResolver, FreeMarkerConfigurer and a path in which files to be processed by freemarker are stored. My problem is that one of the files is actually not a ftl file and it shouldn't be processed. It's located with other actually-ftl files, and I can't find any easy way of excluding it from the ViewResolver in its API.

Is there a way I can disable freemarker template parsing for the whole file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done with

```
<#noparse>
your.entire[#not-a-FTL]FILE ${aaa}
</#noparse>
```